# How to perform inner join 3 classes in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Album,Genre,User classes as below. user class has a userId. I want to list all the songs belonging to a particular user. For this i used this query:

```
String hql = "select song.title,song.artist,song.rating,song.composer,album.albumName,genre.genreName from model.Song song"+
                     "inner join song.Album as album"+
                     "inner join song.Genre as genre"+
                     "inner join model.Login login"+
                     "where login.userId= :userId";
```

Album and Genre are mapped to Song class.I am not clear on how to relate Song class and Login class.

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "songs")
public class Song implements Serializable {


@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "song_id")
private int songId;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "albums_songs_mapping", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "song_id", referencedColumnName = "song_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "album_id", referencedColumnName = "album_id"))
private Album album;

@Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
private String title;

@Column(name = "rating")
private int rating;

@Column(name = "artists")
private String artist;

@Column(name = "composer")
private String composer;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "genre_songs_mapping", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "song_id",      
referencedColumnName = "song_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id", 
referencedColumnName = "genre_id"))
private Genre genre;
//getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "albums")
public class Album {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "album_id")
private int albumId;

@Column(name = "album_name", length = 250)
private String albumName;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
@JoinTable(name = "albums_songs_mapping", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "album_id",   
referencedColumnName = "album_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "song_id", 
referencedColumnName = "song_id"))
private List<Song> songs;

//getters and setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "genre")
public class Genre {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "genre_id")
private int genreId;

@Column(name = "genre_name", length = 250)
private String genreName;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
@JoinTable(name = "genre_songs_mapping", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id", 
referencedColumnName = "genre_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "song_id", 
referencedColumnName = "song_id"))
private List<Song> songs;
//getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "login", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = 
{"user_name"})})
public class Login {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "user_id")
private int userId;

@Column(name = "user_name", nullable=false )
private String userName;

@Column(name = "password", nullable=false )
private String password;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_songs_mapping", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = " user_id", 
referencedColumnName = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "song_id", 
referencedColumnName = "song_id"))
private List<Song> songs;
//getters and setters
}
```

Comment: What are you using actually, `HQL` or `Criteria API`

Comment: I am using hql.
session.createQuery(hql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier if you start from `Login`. Try this:

```
String hql = "select song.title, song.artist, song.rating, song.composer, album.albumName, genre.genreName " 
    + "from Login l join l.songs song "
    + "join song.genre genre " 
    + "join song.album album " 
    + "where l.userId= :userId";
```

Comment: Hey thank you. I am getting the objects from database but I am getting a class cast exception when I try to cast them in List<Song>.
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.List

Comment: @kumuda That's because you are returning a list of separate fields from different entities. If you want `List<Song>` to be returned, just change the `select` clause in the query to `select song from ...`

Comment: Hey predrag . I changed my hql to

String hql = "select song " + "from Login l join l.songs song "
    + "join song.genre genre " + "join song.album album "
    + "where l.userId= :userId";
  Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
  query.setParameter("userId", userId);
  for (Iterator it = query.iterate(); it.hasNext();) {

   songs = (List<Song>) it.next();
  }


But I am still getting a class cast exception.

java.lang.ClassCastException: model.Song cannot be cast to java.util.List

Comment: You should call `List<Song> songs = query.list()`, not `query.iterate()`

Comment: Thank you. That was it. I wasn't using .list().